# Find if the array contain a 2 next to a 2

Tags: python, debugging

I am stuck on this problem

> Given an array of ints, return True if the array contains a 2 next to a 2 somewhere.

```
has22([1, 2, 2]) → True
has22([1, 2, 1, 2]) → False
has22([2, 1, 2]) → False
```

I know the basic idea (there are syntax errors) but I can't implement it. I would also like to know what type of problem this is, eg. graph, search?

```
def has22(nums):
for x in nums:
    if ( (nums[x] = 2) and (nums[x+1] = 2) )
        return True

return False
```

Comment: You have a bit of a logical error in that you can't check whether an element and the next element are both 2 for every element in the list, because the last element doesn't have a next element. It's unclear what the question is here, though. Are you asking how to fix your syntax?

Answer (score 9):

```
def has22(nums):
    return any(x == y == 2 for x, y in zip(nums, nums[1:]))

>>> has22([1, 2, 2])
True
>>> has22([1, 2, 1, 2])
False
>>> has22([2, 1, 2])
False
```

In Python 2 use: `from itertools import izip` if you want a lazy `zip`

Comment: +1. `zip` to iterate in overlapping pairs is a better tool here than anything based on index manipulation.

Answer (score 7):

Potentially the simplest solution:

```
def has22(nums):
    return (2, 2) in zip(nums, nums[1:])
```

---

Suppose `nums == [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. It then [follows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) that `nums[1:] == [2, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. The [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function, when called as `zip(nums, nums[1:])`, zips them into an iterator of the same tuples as below:

```
nums      =>  [1,      2,      2,      3,      4,      5]
nums[1:]  =>  [2,      2,      3,      4,      5]
zip()     =>  [(1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

And it should be clear how `(2, 2) in [(1, 2), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]` is true. This is the same result as `(2, 2) in zip(nums, nums[1:])`.

Answer (score 4):

```
def has22(nums):
    for x in range(len(nums)-1):
        if (nums[x] == 2) and (nums[x+1] == 2):
            return True
    return False
```

I have just corrected your code. It runs in linear time so don't see any reason to work on it further.

Here is the running code on codebunk. http://codebunk.com/bunk#-Ivk7Xw2blX3cIWavI17

Comment: This is really what `any()` is for (see the solution by A. R. S.).

Answer (score 1):

Use `enumerate()` to get both index as well as item, iterating over list only returns it's elements not index.

```
def has22(lis):
    for i,x in enumerate(lis[:-1]):
       if x==2 and lis[i+1]==2:
           return True
    return False

>>> has22([1, 2, 2]) 
True
>>> has22([1, 2, 1, 2])
False
>>> has22([2, 1, 2])
False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`iter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter):

```
>>> def has22(lst):
...     lst = iter(lst)
...     for i in lst:
...             try:
...                 if i == 2 and lst.next() == 2:
...                     return True
...             except StopIteration:
...                     pass
...     return False
... 
>>> has22([1, 2, 2])
True
>>> has22([1, 2, 1, 2])
False
>>> has22([2, 1, 2])
False
```

Comment: Not bad, but a little hard to read: it takes more time to understand how this solution works (`and` is lazy and evaluates from the left,…), compared to the `zip()` and index solutions. Note: `pass` would be simpler as the more direct  `break`, here.

Comment: @EOL I agree with you. `zip()` seems to be the best thing to use

Answer (score 1):

```
def has22(nums):
    it = iter(nums)
    return any(x == 2 == next(it, None) for x in it)

>>> has22([1, 2, 2])
True
>>> has22([1, 2, 1, 2])
False
>>> has22([2, 1, 2])
False
```

Comment: @Haidro You are allowed to answer twice, this is a completely different answer so I don't want to mix up people who didn't vote for it :)

Comment: I'm aware of that, it just seems reasonable to add it on your previous one

Comment: @Haidro meh, some people may not like this one you never know, better keep it separate

Comment: Silly :p. But you're choice :)

Comment: @Haidro I have noticed something weird from creating this, will post as a question now

Comment: Any reason why you didn't just write `x == 2 == next(it)` and used the `and` version instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
def has22(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
        if nums[i] == 2 and nums[i + 1] == 2:
            return True
    return False
```

This was the simplest solution I came up with.

Using a for loop to check if the iterated number, `nums[i] == 2` "and" the one very next to it, `[i+1] == 2` as well.

`(len(nums)-1)`: this line prevents it from going out of the range through the for loop as the `i+1` on the final loop will check out of the range.

Answer (score 1):

```
def has22(nums):
    return '22' in ''.join(map(str, nums))
```

list [1, 2, 2] -> str '122'
return `'22'` in `'122'`

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
def has22(l):
    return any(l[i]==2 and l[i+1]==2 for i in xrange(len(l)-1))
```

This uses a similar idea as the other answers, but works with a generator (as would be preferred in cases like this).

Comment: +1: Clear and simple. I still prefer the index-less `zip()` version, but this comes as a close second.

Answer (score 0):

```
def has22(lst):
  pos = 0 
  while True:
    try:
      next = lst.index(2, pos) + 1
    except ValueError:
      return False
    if next == pos + 1:
      return True
    pos = next
```

This uses the idea that `index()` might be faster due to being implemented not in Python.  Didn't measure it, though.

Concerning your questions:  Your code suffers from not using `range()` at the `for` loop init.  The way you put it, `x` will not be the indexes but the elements of your list.  And it also suffers from using `=` for comparison (which actually just is assignment).  Use `==` for comparison.

This is not a graph problem, it is a simple search issue.  There are quite nifty `strstr` solutions (besides the straight-forward one) for [finding strings in strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore%E2%80%93Horspool_algorithm) (what you actually do).

Answer (score 0):

`def has22(nums):
  for i in range(len(nums)-1):
    if nums[i:i+2] == [2,2]:
      return True
  return False`

Comment: Please elaborate and improve this answer.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

```
    def has22(nums):
      if len(nums)==0:
        return False
      for i in range(len(nums)-1):
        #print nums[i:i+2]
        if nums[i:i+2]==[2,2]:
          return True
      return False
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
def has_22(nums):
    desired = [2, 2]
    if str(desired)[1:-1] in str(nums):
        return True
    else:
        return False
    pass
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post.

Comment: Please help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service, by augmenting your code-only answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Just using index

```
def has22(nums):
    return nums[nums.index(2)+1] == 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def two_two(nums):
  if nums.count(2)==2:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
>>> ls = [1, 2, 2]
>>> s = str(ls)
>>> '2, 2' in s
>>> True
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```py
def has22(nums):
     for i in range(0,len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i:i+2] == [2,2]
           return True
     return False
```

this function checks every 2 value chunk of the input to see if it contains `[2,2]`

Comment: This is the simple way to solve the issue.You can write these lines in your IDE and check it. It works for me properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
def has22(nums):
  
  
  for i in range(len(nums)-1):
    if nums[i] == 2 and nums[i+1] == 2:
      return True
  return False
```

Answer (score 0):

The function argument can be tuple or list, hence, we should check both via "or".

```
def has33(int_array):
for i in range(0, len(int_array)):
    if int_array[i:i+2] == [3, 3] or int_array[i:i+2] == (3, 3):
        return True 
return False

# check
print(has33((2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3)))

# check
print(has33([1, 3, 3]))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def has22(nums):
    numbers = str(nums)
        if numbers.count('2, 2') >=1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Consider including a short description of your code and how it solves the posted problem in order to help others understand your solution

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: -1: no explanation (see above comments), invalid syntax (the indent on `if`), unidiomatic containment check (`'2, 2' in numbers` rather than `numbers.count('2, 2') >= 1`), and overwrought boolean check (`return '2, 2' in numbers` rather than `if` -> `return True` -> `else` -> `return False`)

Answer (score -2):

```py
def has22(nums):
    for x in range(0, len(nums)-1):
        if nums[x] == 2 and nums[x+1] == 2:
            return True

    return False
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Although your code snippet may resolve OP's problem, an explanation of the code will make your answer even better.