# Generator expression never raises StopIteration

Tags: python, iterator, generator

Inspired by [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16813796/1219006), I didn't even understand how it worked myself, consider the following:

```
def has22(nums):
    it = iter(nums)
    return any(x == 2 == next(it) for x in it)


>>> has22([2, 1, 2])
False
```

I expected a `StopIteration` to be raised, since upon reaching `2`, `next(it)` would be advancing a consumed iterator. However it appears that this behavior has been completely disabled, for generator expressions only! The generator expression seems to immediately `break` once this happens.

```
>>> it = iter([2, 1, 2]); any(x == 2 == next(it) for x in it)
False
>>> it = iter([2, 1, 2]); any([x == 2 == next(it) for x in it])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#114>", line 1, in <module>
    it = iter([2, 1, 2]); any([x == 2 == next(it) for x in it])
StopIteration
>>> def F(nums):
        it = iter(nums)
        for x in it:
            if x == 2 == next(it): return True


>>> F([2, 1, 2])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#117>", line 1, in <module>
    F([2, 1, 2])
  File "<pyshell#116>", line 4, in F
    if x == 2 == next(it): return True
StopIteration
```

Even this works!

```
>>> it=iter([2, 1, 2]); list((next(it), next(it), next(it), next(it))for x in it)
[]
```

So I guess my question is, why is this behavior enabled for generator expressions?

<sub>**Note:** Same behavior in `3.x`</sub>

Comment: Inspired by my comments as well. I know, I'm so famous right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The devs have decided that allowing this was a mistake because it can mask obscure bugs. Because of that, the acceptance of [PEP 479](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/)  means this is going away.

In Python 3.5 if you do `from __future__ import generator_stop`, and in Python 3.7 by default, the example in the question will fail with a `RuntimeError`. You could still achieve the same effect (allowing `nums` to not be precomputed) with some itertools magic:

```
from itertools import tee, islice

def has22(nums):
    its = tee(nums, 2)
    return any(x == y == 2 for x, y in 
               zip(its[0], islice(its[1], 1, None)))
```

The reason it ever worked in the first place has to do with how generators work. You can think of this for loop:

```
for a in b:
    # do stuff
```

As being (roughly) equivalent to this:

```
b = iter(b) 
while True:
    try:
        a = next(b)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    else:
        # do stuff
```

Now, all the examples have *two* for loops nested together (one in the generator expression, one in the function consuming it), so that the inner loop iterates once when the outer loop performs its `next` call. What happens when the '# do stuff' in the inner loop is `raise StopIteration`?

```
>>> def foo(): raise StopIteration
>>> list(foo() for x in range(10))
[]
```

The exception propagates out of the inner loop, since it isn't in its guard, and gets caught by the *outer* loop. Under the new behavior, Python will intercept a `StopIteration` that is about to propagate out of a generator  and replace it with a `RuntimeError`, which *won't* be caught by the containing for loop.

This also has the implication that code like this:

```
def a_generator():
     yield 5
     raise StopIteration
```

will also fail, and the mailing list thread gives the impression that this was considered bad form anyway. The proper way to do this is:

```
def a_generator():
    yield 5
    return
```

As you pointed out, list comprehensions already behave differently:

```
>>> [foo() for x in range(10)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in foo
StopIteration
```

This is somewhat an implementation detail leaking - list comprehensions *don't* get transformed into a call to `list` with an equivalent generator expression, and apparently doing so [would cause large performance penalties](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2014-November/029913.html) that the powers that be consider prohibitive.

Comment: Quite intersting - and confusing. Thanks for pointing out the "inconsistency" with Py3 and list comps...

Comment: Your last example propagates the exception because it builds up the list before calling `any`. Nothing inside the `[]` is evaluated after `any` is entered.

Comment: Great answer noting the PEP479 that actually does in fact raise a `RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration` now, validating my surprise at the behaviour in older Pythons. I think your `itertools` magic is a bit overdoing it however, I could simply change `next(it)` to `next(it, None)` and it works great. Feel free to replace that part of your answer with this simpler solution

Answer (score 4):

Interesting behaviour, but absolutely understandable.

If you transform your generator expression to a generator:

```
def _has22_iter(it):
    for x in it:
        yield x == 2 and x == next(it)

def has22(nums):
    it = iter(nums)
    return any(_has22_iter(it))
```

your generator raises `StopIteration` in the following conditions:

- the generator function reaches its end
- there is a `return` statement somewhere
- there is a `raise StopIteration` somewhere

Here, you have the third condition, so the generator is terminated.

Compare with the following:

```
def testgen(x):
    if x == 0:
        next(iter([])) # implicitly raise
    if x == 1:
        raise StopIteration
    if x == 2:
        return
```

and do

```
list(testgen(0)) # --> []
list(testgen(1)) # --> []
list(testgen(2)) # --> []
list(testgen(3)) # --> []
```

you get the same behaviour in all cases.

Comment: This isn't quite the same - a `StopIteration` raised by a generator will always come up in the loop's own call to `next`, and never in the effective body of the loop. Try instead `for _ in range(10): raise StopIteration` - you get a traceback.

Comment: ah this makes complete sense now, I think I thought my function `F` was a generator for a second

Comment: @lvc You get a traceback, yes - but if used inside a generator, it will be caught in this context.

Comment: @glglgl it will be caught by whatever is iterating over the generator results, rather than by the generator itself. This *would* explain why `any` will appear to swallow it (it will occur in *`any`*'s call to `next` and signal 'normal iterator end') - except that list comprehensions *don't*, despite (especially in Python 3) behaving as syntactic sugar for `list(genexp)`. And, especially, why `any` propogates the exception from a listcomp, not from a genexp - that implies that it is the *generator itself* ending early, rather than whatever is consuming it.

Comment: @glglgl I've edited my own answer to add a less cramped discussion of my point.