# StopIteration in generators

Tags: python-3.x, iterator, generator

I'm learning python's generators, iterators, iterables, and I can't explain why the following is not working. I want to create, as an exercise, a simple version of the function zip. Here's what i did:

```
def myzip(*collections):

    iterables = tuple(iter(collection) for collection in collections)

    yield tuple(next(iterable) for iterable in iterables)

test = myzip([1,2,3],(4,5,6),{7,8,9})

print(next(test))
print(next(test))
print(next(test))
```

What I do is:

- I have `collections` which is a tuple of some collections
- I create a new tuple `iterables` where, for each collection (which is iterable), I get the iterator using `iter`
- Then, I create a new tuple where, on each iterable, I call `next`. This tuple is then yield.

So I expect that at the first execution the object `iterables` is created (and stored). Then in each iteration (including the first one) I call `next` on every iterable stored before and return it.

However this is what I get:

```
(1, 4, 8)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-424963a58e58> in <module>()
      8 
      9 print(next(test))
---> 10 print(next(test))

StopIteration:
```

So I see that the first iteration is fine and the result is correct. However, the second iteration raise a StopIteration exception and I don't understand why: each iterable still has some values, so none of the `next`s return StopIteration. In fact, this works:

```
def myziptest(*collections):

    iterables = tuple(iter(collection) for collection in collections)

    for _ in range(3):
        print(tuple(next(iterable) for iterable in iterables))

test = myziptest([1,2,3],(4,5,6),{7,8,9})
```

Output:

```
(1, 4, 8)
(2, 5, 9)
(3, 6, 7)
```

So what is going on?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working solution

```
def myzip(*collections):

    iterables = tuple(iter(collection) for collection in collections)

    while True:
        try:
            yield tuple([next(iterable) for iterable in iterables])
        except StopIteration:
            # one of the iterables has no more left.                
            break

test = myzip([1,2,3],(4,5,6),{7,8,9})

print(next(test))
print(next(test))
print(next(test))
```

The difference between this code and yours is that your code only yields **one** result. Meaning, calling **next** more than once will give you a StopIteration.

Think of `yield x` as putting `x` into a queue, and `next` as popping from that queue. And when you try to pop from an empty queue, you get the `Stopiteration`. You can pop only as many as you put.

Comment: Ok that was really a stupid mistake... I forgot to add a cycle, so clearly the function died after the first next().

Thank you!

Comment: no problem. FYI, the `tuple(next(iterable) for iterable in iterables)` will continue to work even when the collections aren't of the same size. making it `tuple([next(iterable) for iterable in iterables])` will trigger a StopIteration, so you can stop at the shortest common length.

Comment: In fact, I'm seeing that if I do `for i in test: print(i)` I get an endless loop. What's the difference?

Comment: The difference is, `tuple(i for i in foo)` is `tuple(generator)`, and the generator can return something empty. `tuple([i for i in foo])` is `tuple(list)` which forces the generator to unroll. And when it does unroll (pardon my terms), the `next(...)` triggers the `StopIteration`. Here's an example - [link](https://repl.it/Hm57/0)

Comment: I've updated the code so no one else is surprised by the infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks! Ok perhaps this is OT, however I didn't know that generators may return something empty. 

I knew that generator expressions or generator functions, being iterators, produce the next value using `next` if available, otherwise they raise a `StopIteration` exception.

So a generator in a for loop should behave exactly the same as a list (obtaining an instance of `list.iter()`), being both an iterator.

So why in this case the generator is behaving differently? Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you using python 3.4 ? Try this [link](https://repl.it/Hm57/1).
Also check out this stackoverflow question [generator-expression-never-raises-stopiteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814111/generator-expression-never-raises-stopiteration)

Comment: No I'm using 3.6. However from your comments #1 and #2 since you explicitly mentioned this difference between generators vs lists in my code without knowing python version, I presume that is a language feature not related to that bug?